# How to make working progress bar in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a progress bar like this:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="import_bar" Minimum="0"  Maximum="100" Orientation="Horizontal"  Value="{Binding CurrentProgress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

and the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewImportProgressViewModel  : BindableBase
    {   
        MainTest mainTest;

        public double CurrentProgress { get; set; }

        public ViewImportProgressViewModel(MainTest mainTest) //constructor
        {
            this.mainTest = mainTest;
            mainTest.ProgressUpdated += SetProgressBarValue;
        }

         private void SetProgressBarValue(double argument)
        {

            CurrentProgress = argument * 100;
            OnPropertyChanged(() => CurrentProgress);
        }

    }
```

and the test class that actually sets the value for the progress:

```
public class MainTest
    {
        public delegate void ProgressUpdateHandler(double argument);
        public event ProgressUpdateHandler ProgressUpdated;

        public void RunTheLoop()
        {
            double progress=0;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
                {
                    //lenghty task code

                    .......


                    //increment the progress bar
                    progress += 1 / 30;


                    if (i == 30)
                        progress = 1;


                    ProgressUpdated(progress);

                }

        }

    }
```

Code runs OK, and I see that `CurrentProgress` gets correct value, but the progress bar in the UI does not update. Can somebody please help me with this?

Update;

If I use non-MVVM approach in code behind like this:

```
 public delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);            
 UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(progress_bar.SetValue);
 Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, new object[] { System.Windows.Controls.ProgressBar.ValueProperty, CurrentProgress });
```

then it works.

Comment: What does `ProgressUpdated` do?

Comment: It sends 'progress' to the ViewModel, so each time 'progress' gets updated, 'SetProgressBarValue()' gets called in the ViewModel and passes this value to the 'CurrentProgress' property

Comment: Does your `ViewImportProgressViewModel` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, it implements 'BindableBase' since I use Prism

Comment: Have you tried debugging? You would found very quickly, tak your progress is always 0, because 1 / 30 is always 0, since you are using integers, not decimals.

Comment: If the value is set correctly then your Binding is not working. Look for errors in there.

Comment: Well, I guess it does. Because after the loop finishes, the progress bar instantly jumps to 100%

Comment: @Ivan please check my updated answer I have included a section to explain if you are performing all your actions on the UI thread. If at the end of processing it jumps to 100% then it does not look like a binding issue but a busy UI thread issue.

Comment: Which thread do you run the test on? If it's on the UI thread, I'd expect exactly what you see, i.e. no updates on the ui until the very last one.

Comment: Yes, it is on the main thread. It apparently doesn't let me run it on separate thread, or maybe if I go run each sub-calling method on a separate thread? Please see my replies below

Comment: So my real question now becomes: How to call a method on different thread, and all method calls inside that method on the same different thread?

Comment: Use `Dispatcher` and then `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => //your stuff here)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather crude approach but it does work using an MVVM approach

**MainTest**

```
public class MainTest
{
    public delegate void ProgressUpdateHandler(double argument);
    public event ProgressUpdateHandler ProgressUpdated;

    public void RunTheLoop()
    {
        // This does not work
        //this.PerformStuff();

        // This does
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.PerformStuff());
    }

    private void PerformStuff()
    {
        double progress = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            //increment the progress bar
            progress += 1.0 / 30;


            if (i == 30)
                progress = 1;


            ProgressUpdated(progress);

        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MainTest test;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.test = new MainTest();
        this.DataContext = new ViewImportProgressViewModel(this.test);

        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.test.RunTheLoop();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewImportProgressViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    MainTest mainTest;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double CurrentProgress { get; set; }

    public ViewImportProgressViewModel(MainTest mainTest) //constructor
    {
        this.mainTest = mainTest;
        mainTest.ProgressUpdated += SetProgressBarValue;
    }

    private void SetProgressBarValue(double argument)
    {

        CurrentProgress = argument * 100;

        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("CurrentProgress"));
    }

}
```

Comment: I can try it but I am almost certain that I do perform on the main thread, and I already thought of this as a problem. I tried to  move the 'RunTheLoop()' on separate thread, but then I get the exception 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).'

Comment: My 'lengthy task code' consists of calls to the methods that come from hierarchical model classes, and the exception that I mentioned is thrown in one of these methods

Comment: @Ivan There isn't a huge amount I can do to help fix that without seeing the code which I would assume you wouldn't want to post on here. Can you try commenting out your 'length task code' and replace it with a Thread.Sleep to prove whether it is the UI thread that is being blocked? If that is the case I would suggest trying to break down the model classes to work out how to fix the threading issue.

Comment: Yes, I replaced the calls to the methods with Therad.Sleep(2000); and I get the same thing (empty progress bar that at the end jumps to 100.

Comment: @Ivan is that using the sample I supplied with calling Task.Factory.StartNew?

Comment: no no, without it. I'll try using Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: I just tried it, but I get the same exception: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)).

Comment: Please see my updated question for a code-behind approach that works and maybe based on this try to understand why the mvvm one doesn't

Comment: @Ivan I have modified my answer to give a rough MVVM approach that does work

Comment: @Ivan if you want to update your UI async in a task, you need to include synchronizasion context which needs to be current. As only UI thread can update the UI, then you should not get this exception. If you google SynchronizationContext you should find some answers, hope this helps )